# Filtering out a row with a null value

Tags: mysql

How would I filter out a row with a null value?

```
SELECT country_table.country as country, 
(SELECT TRUNCATE(AVG(news_guard_score), 3) FROM news WHERE news.country_id = country_table.country_id) as 'avg_news_score'
FROM country_table
-- WHERE country_table.country_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY country;
```

It does not work with the commented code

[How it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zIqn.png)

I need it without the final row

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT country_table.country as country, 
(SELECT TRUNCATE(AVG(news_guard_score), 3) FROM news WHERE (news.country_id = country_table.country_id AND country_table.country_id IS NOT NULL)) as 'avg_news_score'
FROM country_table
GROUP BY country;
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a `HAVING` clause:

```sql
SELECT c.country, TRUNCATE(AVG(n.news_guard_score), 3)
FROM country_table c
INNER JOIN news n ON n.country_id = c.country_id
GROUP BY c.country
HAVING AVG(n.news_guard_score) IS NOT NULL;
```

Note: I have rewritten your query to use a direct inner join, rather than the correlated subquery which you were using (and which would probably not perform too well).